# Put a Home icon in top menu

Tags: topmenu

I've looked in the existing post I couldn´t really find an answer..

So my question is simple : I already have a "Home" menu before all my menu, but this is a simple text. I'd like to put Font awesome icon, or at least a picture but the title of the category doesn't allow to put image or any code.

```
    <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

How could I put a icon before all of my menus ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT : does the file to edit is find in the here : app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html 
 ??

I edited topmenu.phtml with this but nothing shows up ... and i did the same for top.phtml..

```
   <ul id="nav">
<li class="first home"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('home') ?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use css to add your desired icons. Please provide a link or screenshot what you exactly require.

Comment: Ok so I did all of this and it works, but not with my module. www.ch-test.com check it out. So how can you guide me do to the exact same thing but in the module thing ? Thanks in advance a lot EDIT : sorry for the double post

Answer (score 1):

You need to make note of which package and theme you are using and edit the file according to what ever it is set to in the admin backend (System -> Configuration -> Design - package + themes).

The file to edit is: `app/design/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` as you mentioned above so that it looks like:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <li class="first home"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('home') ?>">Home</a></li>
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

Then you can edit the css in order to get the image to show in:`skin/frontend/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/css/styles.css`

Once thats done, be sure to clear the Magento cache in order for the changes to appear.

Comment: Ok thanks for all of this, i'll come back to you if it works or not :)